# How rsnapshot manages moved and/or renamed files and folders

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot

I consider using rsnapshot for backuping large amount of data and I wonder how rsnapshot manage when a folder at the source is moved or rename, is it detected it and edit associated hard links or it creates "duplicate" of all the files tree under?

Answer (score 2):

If the source folder is renamed/moved, `rsnapshot` (or `rsync`) does **not** detect the change. In other words, the renamed directory will be re-copied without hardlinks. To avoid that, if/when you know a big source directory has been renamed, you should do the same on the latest backup directory (ie: inside `daily.0`).

Comment: Ok, thanks. But if I noticed the renaming a couple backup after, in the daily.0, wouldn't the folder with its "old name" not be shown cause it do not exists anymore in the source?

Comment: Let's say a backupped dir was renamed from `oldname/` to `newname/`. If you want to avoid data duplication at the next backup run, you had to `cd daily.0/` and `mv oldname/ newname/`. You need to do that **before** the next backup run.